# Script that makes points collect and go somewhere else effecting everything with a "istrigger" tag

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine, triggers

I'm having some trouble, every time i hit anything with a collider that has a trigger on it, it spawns a point and deletes the object that has a trigger, I'm thinking of adding a layer or tag to the collectible point that the script will detect and only effect objects with the tag or layer, but cant figure this out.

Here is my code

```
using System.Collections;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using UnityEngine;

public class Collect : MonoBehaviour
{
    private Rigidbody2D rb;

    [SerializeField]
    private GameObject Point;

    // Start is called before the first frame update
    void Start()
    {
        rb = GetComponent<Rigidbody2D>();
        SpawnPoint();
    }

    // Update is called once per frame
    void Update()
    {
    
    }

    private void FixedUpdate()
    {
    }

    private void SpawnPoint()
    {
        bool pointSpawned = false;
        while (!pointSpawned)
        {
            Vector3 pointPosition =  new Vector3(Random.Range(-13f, 13f), Random.Range(-8f, 8f), 0f);
            if ((pointPosition - transform.position).magnitude <  3)
            {
                continue;     
            }
            else
            {
                Instantiate(Point, pointPosition, Quaternion.identity);
                pointSpawned = true;
            }
        }
    }

    private void OnTriggerEnter2D(Collider2D collision)
    {
        Destroy(collision.gameObject);
        SpawnPoint();
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use the `CompareTag` function to check if the object is of a certain tag.

Try this:

```
OnEnterTrigger2D(Collider2D collision)
{
    if(collision.collider.gameobject.CompareTag("The tag you want to compare"))
    {
        Destroy(collision.gameObject);
        SpawnPoint();
    }
}
```

Comment: i had a problem, i changed nothing, and it worked, 10/10 would do again.